# Laravel - How to orderBy eloquent query with pivot and each function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with orderBy in more complicated query.

**I want to get 10 ordered users (pivot with club) from specified club and hide some columns.**

So I have query in eloquent which almost works for me. The problem is with **ordering users** by some variable (level or exp - don't know yet).

**My query (working - without ordering):**

```
        $users = Club::find($club_id)->users->each(function($row) {

            $row->setHidden(['history', 'books', 'reviews', 'exp', 'erudion_id', 'phone', 'bio', 'active', 'book_transfer_type', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'active_club', 'facebook_id', 'password_token', 'points', 'password_status', 'pivot']);

        })->take(10);

    return $users;
```

**One of my trials (with OrderBy):**

```
    //
//        $users = Club::find($club_id)->with(['users' => function ($q) {
//
//            $q->orderBy('id');
//
//        }])->each(function($row) {
//
//            $row->setHidden(['history', 'books', 'reviews', 'exp', 'erudion_id', 'phone', 'bio', 'active', 'book_transfer_type', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'active_club', 'facebook_id', 'password_token', 'points', 'password_status', 'pivot']);
//
//        });
//
//        return $users;
```

Error:

> The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

I have appended attributes in my model. This attributes cannot be unselected by not including them in select, so they are basically always selected.

I want to create eloquent query which will limit attributes to only few, which interest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out in different way. Maybe it not looks so good but it works. Works much faster than without hidden attributes.

I use in my models appended attributes, which are always selected (even without selecting them in eloquent) so I had to create array with attributes which interest me.

```
  $users = Club::where('id', $club_id)->first()->users()->orderBy('id')->limit(10)->get();

    $ranking = [];

    foreach($users as $k => $user){
        $ranking[$k]['id'] = $user['id'];
        $ranking[$k]['f_name'] = $user['f_name'];
        ...
    }

    return $ranking;
```

Thank you guys for clues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try as:

```
$users = Club::where('id', $club_id)
                ->first()
                ->users()
                ->select('id', 'name') // you can add more columns which you want to select
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->get()

return $users;
```

**Update**

Or if you want use `each` then you can do as:

```
$users = Club::where('id', $club_id)
                ->first()
                ->users()
                ->orderBy('id')
                ->get()
                ->each(function($user) {
                    $user->setHidden(['history', 'books', 'reviews', 'exp', 'erudion_id', 'phone', 'bio', 'active', 'book_transfer_type', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'active_club', 'facebook_id', 'password_token', 'points', 'password_status', 'pivot']);
                });

return $users;
```

Comment: Yep, but I have problem with hidding some attributes. In model I have a lot of appended attributes which select always shows. Each function does'ny work with this query:         `->each(function($row) {

            $row->setHidden(['history', 'books', 'reviews', 'exp', 'erudion_id', 'phone', 'bio', 'active', 'book_transfer_type', 'email', 'password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'active_club', 'facebook_id', 'password_token', 'points', 'password_status', 'pivot']);

        });`